# jquery change class and inline style of a div when another div is clicked

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, nested, styles

this is my html -

```
<div id="5bdf3284466d57.18631639">
    <div class="tm-collapse tmaccordion">
        <h3 class="tm-epo-field-label tm-section-label tm-toggle">Display and glass
            <span class="tcfa tm-arrow tcfa-angle-down"></span>
        </h3>
        <div class="tm-collapse-wrap closed" style="display: none;">      
            <p>The display / glass of your device is broken, cracked 
                or damaged or your touch screen no longer responds.</p>         
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i have another div tag somewhere in the page which is

```
<div id="displayandglass">Display and glass</div>
```

i am trying to have a jquery click event so that when

```
<div id="displayandglass">Display and glass</div>
```

is clicked then the class and style of one of the above newsted div will change from -

```
<div class="tm-collapse-wrap closed" style="display: none;">
```

to

```
<div class="tm-collapse-wrap" style="display: block;">
```

Because of the nested level, i am unable to do so. can someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add a click event on your `#displayandglass` div that removes `close` class & `style` attribute (`display:block;` is the default one for a `<div>` so it is not necessary to add that rule inline).

```js
$("#displayandglass").on("click", function(event){
    $(".tm-collapse-wrap").removeAttr("style").removeClass("closed");
    /* --> $(".tm-collapse-wrap").removeClass("closed").css("display", "block"); */
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="5bdf3284466d57.18631639">
    <div class="tm-collapse tmaccordion">
      <h3 class="tm-epo-field-label tm-section-label tm-toggle">Display and glass
        <span class="tcfa tm-arrow tcfa-angle-down"></span>
      </h3>
      <div class="tm-collapse-wrap closed" style="display: none;">      
        <p>The display / glass of your device is broken, cracked or damaged or your touch screen no longer responds.</p>         
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="displayandglass">Display and glass</div>
```

**EDIT 1**

Because your ID have a period (.) you have to use this sintax: `#5bdf3284466d57\\.18631639` to select it (it is better to use a hyphen, for exemple, rather than a period)

```js
$("#displayandglass").on("click", function(event){
    $("#5bdf3284466d57\\.18631639 .tm-collapse-wrap").removeAttr("style").removeClass("closed");
    /* --> $(".tm-collapse-wrap").removeClass("closed").css("display", "block"); */
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="5bdf3284466d57.18631639">
    <div class="tm-collapse tmaccordion">
      <h3 class="tm-epo-field-label tm-section-label tm-toggle">Display and glass
        <span class="tcfa tm-arrow tcfa-angle-down"></span>
      </h3>
      <div class="tm-collapse-wrap closed" style="display: none;">      
        <p>The display / glass of your device is broken, cracked or damaged or your touch screen no longer responds.</p>         
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="displayandglass">Display and glass</div>
```

Comment: There are number of <div class="tm-collapse-wrap closed" style="display: none;">  How do i catch the one which is inside the parent div (also having unique ID), in this case <div id="5bdf3284466d57.18631639">. It seems its the child of the first child.

Comment: I thried this but dosent works - $("#5bdf3284466d57.18631639 .tm-collapse-wrap").removeAttr("style").removeClass("closed");

Comment: ...and your `#displayandglass` open all `.tm-collapse-wrap`? How many `#displayandglass` do you have in the page?? ID's have to be unique. Maybe it is better to edit your question 'cause it is not so clear.

Comment: #displayandglass is just one and also unique. You code previous code works but it opens up all the .tm-collapse-wrap. i just need to catch the one which is inside <div id="5bdf3284466d57.18631639">

Comment: Thanks a ton...worked like a charm.. The dot in the ID was screwing up.

Comment: You're welcome! Yep, a period is also an identifier for class so you have to use \\. Because of this 'problem', and only if you can, change it with hypen or undescore. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your **div** and use it as a selector.

```js
function showData() {
  $(".description").css('display', 'block');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="5bdf3284466d57.18631639">
  <div class="tm-collapse tmaccordion">
    <h3 class="tm-epo-field-label tm-section-label tm-toggle">Display and glass
      <span class="tcfa tm-arrow tcfa-angle-down"></span>
    </h3>
    <!-- 
         Using "description" class, you can use whatever you like, 
         or even use an ID. Use "." for classes and "#" for id attribute.
     -->
    <div class="tm-collapse-wrap closed description" style="display: none;">
      <p>The display / glass of your device is broken, cracked or damaged 
         or your touch screen no longer responds.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="displayandglass" onclick="showData()">Display and glass</div>
```

For a list of all possible jQuery selectors look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)